# Editing list elements

Tags: r

I have a data frame df that i split up into a large list, and now i'd like to change the elements of the list based on the value (numtake), so for each list element in the below example i would like to change the Init Value to "new" for the first row if numtake=1 and for the first 2 rows if numtake=2 etc.

```
 $TH.9990.1
           Init Monthly  Dlr Cls.Accoun Cur.Balance  meandiff numtake
12920        TH       1 9990 502-******     3949.85  48.30333       1
12921        TH       1 9990 502-******      4112.69 211.14333       1
12922        TH       1 9990 502-******     3642.10 259.44667       1

$VAF.9990.1
           init Monthly  Dlr Cls.Accoun Cur.Balance  meandiff numtake
13834       VAF       1 9990 502-******     2600.24   78.7925       2
13835       VAF       1 9990 502-******      3618.78  939.7475      2
13836       VAF       1 9990 502-******     4337.44 1658.4075       2
13837       VAF       1 9990 502-******      159.67 2519.3625       2
```

Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: Please share any code attempts you have made to receive better direction on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this base R solution should work out:

```
lapply(myList, function(x) within(x, Init[seq_len(numtake[1])] <- rep("new", numtake[1])))

$TH.9990.1
      Init Monthly  Dlr Cls.Accoun Cur.Balance  meandiff numtake       val
12920  new       1 9990 502-******     3949.85  48.30333       1 TH.9990.1
12921   TH       1 9990 502-******     4112.69 211.14333       1 TH.9990.1
12922   TH       1 9990 502-******     3642.10 259.44667       1 TH.9990.1

$VAF.9990.1
      Init Monthly  Dlr Cls.Accoun Cur.Balance  meandiff numtake        val
13834  new       1 9990 502-******     2600.24   78.7925       2 VAF.9990.1
13835  new       1 9990 502-******     3618.78  939.7475       2 VAF.9990.1
13836  VAF       1 9990 502-******     4337.44 1658.4075       2 VAF.9990.1
13837  VAF       1 9990 502-******      159.67 2519.3625       2 VAF.9990.1
```

The first observation of numtake is used to select the number of repeated "new" values in the assignment as well as an argument to `seq_len` to select the element values to use for the replacement in the Init variable. `within` reduces typing and returns the altered data.frame and `lapply` loops through the list.

**data**

```
structure(list(TH.9990.1 = structure(list(Init = c("TH", "TH", 
"TH"), Monthly = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Dlr = c(9990L, 9990L, 9990L), 
    Cls.Accoun = c("502-******", "502-******", "502-******"), 
    Cur.Balance = c(3949.85, 4112.69, 3642.1), meandiff = c(48.30333, 
    211.14333, 259.44667), numtake = c(1L, 1L, 1L), val = c("TH.9990.1", 
    "TH.9990.1", "TH.9990.1")), .Names = c("Init", "Monthly", 
"Dlr", "Cls.Accoun", "Cur.Balance", "meandiff", "numtake", "val"
), row.names = c("12920", "12921", "12922"), class = "data.frame"), 
    VAF.9990.1 = structure(list(Init = c("VAF", "VAF", "VAF", 
    "VAF"), Monthly = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Dlr = c(9990L, 9990L, 
    9990L, 9990L), Cls.Accoun = c("502-******", "502-******", 
    "502-******", "502-******"), Cur.Balance = c(2600.24, 3618.78, 
    4337.44, 159.67), meandiff = c(78.7925, 939.7475, 1658.4075, 
    2519.3625), numtake = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), val = c("VAF.9990.1", 
    "VAF.9990.1", "VAF.9990.1", "VAF.9990.1")), .Names = c("Init", 
    "Monthly", "Dlr", "Cls.Accoun", "Cur.Balance", "meandiff", 
    "numtake", "val"), row.names = c("13834", "13835", "13836", 
    "13837"), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("TH.9990.1", 
"VAF.9990.1"))
```

Comment: So this works when i use the data you created, but when i apply it to my list, it produces NA instead of "new" though it is putting NA in the correct spots.

Comment: Most likely, your Init column is a factor column. You should coerce it to be character. The easiest way to do this is using `as.is=TRUE` in the `read.` family of functions. Otherwise use `df$Init <- as.character(df$Init)` prior to splitting the data.frame.